# Transloadit and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, transloadit

I'm developing an Angular & Firebase app and I want to avoid having any backend outside of Firebase. Documents don't recommend storing images in Firebase, so I wanted to use Trasnloadit to save images. Is there a way to use Transloadit securely to send images directly from my Angular app or Firebase instance?

Comment: It looks like transloadit has a jQuery plugin: https://transloadit.com/docs/#our-jquery-plugin. If you can get the URL from that upload, you could store it in Firebase.

Comment: I'm doing something similar with both Firebase and looking into Transloadit. Yes, it appears you can process images and video with Transloadit without a backend, however if you're going to be completely secure you need to use https://transloadit.com/docs/api-docs/#signature-authentication which requires a signature. I'm curious as to how one might get this signature client-side as well.

Comment: Just a comment the jquery plugin has been deprecated. For client side integration with Transloadit the recommended tool is Uppy with the Transloadit plugin or Robodog. https://uppy.io/docs/robodog/

Answer (score 0):

While, this is an old question it is still worth exploring a possible solution to your question. If you're looking to send data securely with Transloadit you may want to look into [creating a signature](https://transloadit.com/docs/#signature-authentication). Signature authentication works both ways - so you can double-check with Firebase that the source of the file is authenticated, however you need to make sure that you perform this server side. Luckily, Transloadit makes it simple to generate a signature:

1. You want to make an object to replace the params field in your assembly

```
{
  "auth": {
    "key": "23c96d084c744219a2ce156772ec3211",
    "expires": "2021/01/31 16:53:14+00:00",
    // This could also contain your template ID if you're not defining your steps here
  },
  "steps": { ... }
}
```

2. Next, you need to convert this into JSON, for this you can use `JSON.stringify()`|
3. Now, to make this a RFC 2104-compliant HMAC hex signature - you can use a library such as CryptoJS

```
signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, auth_secret).toString(CryptoJS.enc.HEX);
```

Next, for sending the file to a GCS - you can use the [/google/store](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/#google-store) robot. So for example, you could add this snippet to your template:

```
"exported": {
  "use": [
    ":original",
    ...
  ],
  "robot": "/google/store",
  "credentials": "YOUR_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS"
}
```

This robot also has the property `acl` - which determines the permissions that the file has. By default it's `public-read` but you have several options including: `authenticated-read`, `bucket-owner-full-control`, `private`, `project-private`.